# Saving NaiveBayes classifier to disk

Tags: python, nltk, pickle

I've tried implementing other solutions found on stack overflow with no success.

On the first run through I get the results I'm expecting, namely a variety of positive and negative results.  On the second run all I get are positive results no matter what it's reading in.

Here's what my save and load function look like:

```
def save_classifier(self, classifier):
    print 'Saving new classifier.'
    try:
        f = open(self.get_base_path_to_save_classifier(), 'wb')
        pickle.dump(classifier, f)
        f.close()
    except IOError:
        print 'Error'
        return False

def load_classifier(self):
    try:
        f = open(self.get_base_path_to_save_classifier(), 'rb')
        classifier = pickle.load(f)
        f.close()
        return classifier
    except IOError:
        print 'No classifier was found.'
        return None

@staticmethod
def get_base_path_to_save_classifier():
    return os.getcwd() + '/Twitter_Utils/data/classifier.pickle
```

And my main:

```
def analyze_tweets(self):
    naive_bayes_classifier = self.load_classifier()
    if naive_bayes_classifier is None:
        naive_bayes_classifier = self.create_training_set()

    with open(os.getcwd() + '/Twitter_Utils/data/tweets/Hawks-vs-Warriors.txt') as f:
        for line in f:
            print naive_bayes_classifier.classify(self.extract_features(self.create_feature_vector(line)))
```

Comment: Are you using a package to create your classifier?  Does it have documentation for the proper method to save it to disk?

Comment: @sedavidw the suggestion that they have in their documentation is what I've implemented above and what is suggested in a bunch of stack overflow questions.

Comment: what package are you using?

Comment: Your use of pickle looks correct.  I'm guessing that `create_training_set()` is doing something weird, but you're not showing it. `create_training_set` is an odd name for something that should be training a classifier, which reinforces my suspicions. I suggest you run your code from the interactive console to train and save a classifier, then unpickle it into a different variable and compare the two objects. You might notice something. Or include self-sufficient, runnable code in your question (but first simplify your class by taking out irrelevant details).

Comment: @alexis Heres the whole file.  https://gist.github.com/FredLoh/58467c303200986b1f03

Comment: Well, that's complete at least. I took a quick look and nothing jumped out at me, so you're going to have to debug your program yourself. Get in the interactive console, inspect your model as I suggested, construct your classifier step by step and examine your data, etc. When you can encapsulate into a few lines of code (10-15 max) something that doesn't behave as you think it should, come back and ask again.

Comment: Before you do all that, though, you may want to simply adapt your script for python 3 and run it there. If it suddenly works, you're dealing with a version-dependent bug. (Why are you still doing language stuff with python 2, anyway?)